# While doing fixpack upgrade from 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.13 failing with CRIMA1161E ERROR

Tags: websphere-8

I have downloaded the fix pack from below URL.

https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/downloadFixes?parent=ibm%2FWebSphere%E2%88%8Fuct=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+Application+Server&release=All&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP013-part3,8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP013-part2,8.5.5-WS-WAS-FP013-part1%E2%88%88cludeRequisites=1%E2%88%88cludeSupersedes=0&downloadMethod=http&login=true

Upgrade Version - From WebSphere 8.5.5.0 to 8.5.5.13

While running the imcl command i have faced below error. Can someone please suggest what could cause this isssue?

```
# ./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v85_8.5.5013.20180112_1418 -repositories /data/repo/repository.config -installationDirectory /appl/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/ -acceptLicense -showProgress 

                 25%                50%                75%                100%
------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
............................................................................
ERROR: Failed to find required installation files.
  CRIMA1161E ERROR: Failed to find required installation files.
  Explanation: Installation Manager did not find required installation files from the repository. An issue has occurred with the package that cannot be resolved by Installation Manager.
  User Action: If the repository files were transferred from a different location before the installation, verify that the files were not altered during the transfer operation. Copy the repository files to a different location and install from that location. If the repository files were not transferred note the package name and version number and contact customer support.
    ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.detect.offering.update.v85_8.5.0.20120308_0100' not found in /data/repo.
    ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.detect.backlevel.jdk.ifix_8.0.2.20120308_0004' not found in /data/repo.
    ERROR: 'plug-in com.ibm.was.determine.job.type_8.5.0.20120326_1010' not found in /data/repo.
```

Comment: Are you sure 8.5.5.0 is installed in /appl/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/ ?

Comment: @covener: Yes,

Installed Product

Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.5.0
ID                    BASE
Package               com.ibm.websphere.BASE.v85_8.5.5000.20130514_1044

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# pwd
/appl/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have old repositories enabled in Installation Manager preferences, for which the installation files are missing.

Try below steps to resolve this issue:

1. If you can enable GUI, Open IM, go to File > preferences >
   Repositories. Do a test connection for all enabled repositories and
   uncheck/disable repositories that are not working/you no longer
   read.
2. If you cannot enable GUI, there are 2 options

   1. Modify ***com.ibm.cic.agent.core.prefs*** file in order to enable/disable repositories (default location in linux:
      /var/ibm/InstallationManager/.settings/com.ibm.cic.agent.core.prefs)
   2. Enable/Disable repositories using '***imcl -c***' command line https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSDV2W_1.8.5/com.ibm.cic.agent.console.doc/topics/t_console_pref_repository.html#remove_rep

Once old repositories for which installation files are missing are disabled, try installing the fixpack again.

Comment: @M I P: it looks like already enabled


offering.service.repositories.areUsed=true
com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.directArtifactAccessMode_EDITABLE=true
com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.downloadAutoRetryCount=0
com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.defaultProfile_EDITABLE=true
com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.repositoryLocations_EDITABLE=true
offering.service.repositories.areUsed_EDITABLE=true
com.ibm.cic.common.core.preferences.downloadAutoRetryCount_EDITABLE=true